# Problem with Max 485 RS485 to TTL chip (Not Receiving Data)

Tags: arduino, rs485, hardware

I am working on a project connecting Arduino UNO r3 and an RS485 modbus master with MAX485. The connections are shown below.

```
MAX 485---------- UNO
RO---- ------------------RX(0)
DI-----------------------TX(1)
DE,RE---------------------Pin4
VCC--------------------------5V
GND-------------------------GND
A,B ----------- Master A,B
```

The problem is that I do not receive any data from the RO pin of the chip. I checked that the master sends data with an oscilloscope, but no data is present at the RO pin. I have also connected a logic analyzer at then RO Pin and I can not see the packet I send from master.

Comment: Do you drive the RE/DE pins correctly with the Pin4 of your Arduino to enable the data reception ?
RE must be low to allow data to flow on RO

Comment: Please add a data sheet link to the RS485 chip and state the full part number.

Comment: How do you connect to bus? Have you connected the two data wires only? Have you got ground wire too, or otherwise do the devices share the same ground reference through some other route?